# Open an email program with subject and body prefilled is not working correct

Tags: javascript, lotus-notes

I have the following javascript function which should open (in our case lotus notes), with a prefilled email.

```
function emailpage() {
    strTitle = document.title;
    strTitle = strTitle.replace("&","-");
    window.location = "mailto:" + "?subject=I thought this link might interest you." + "&body=" + strTitle + " - " + window.location;
}
```

but instead I am getting this:

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you're not getting a body?

Comment: Never mind, now I see it.

Comment: Try `"mailto:" + "?subject=" + encodeURIComponent("I thought this link might interest you.") + "&body=" + encodeURIComponent(strTitle + " - " + window.location)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replacing body and subject should help you:

```
function emailpage() {
    strTitle = document.title;
    strTitle = strTitle.replace("&","-");
    window.location = "mailto:?body=" + strTitle + " - " + window.location + "&subject=I thought this link might interest you.";
}
```

Comment: this worked, but not 100% of the times, in some pages it didnt work, so I tried the EncodeURI from @andreas and it works 100%